# Correlated explanatory variables in linear regression

Tags: regression, correlation

Is it any reason to assume that if two strongly correlated explanatory variables have impact on response that regression coefficients for these variables have the same signs ? Could such assumption be justified in some way ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess any such justification must come from the subject area, not from statistics.  On purely statistical grounds there is no such justification.